# Parsing json from facebook url and getting value to div

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to get a facebook page like value into a div, but the value is not being printed.

```js
var link='{"url":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?fields=fan_count%2Cnew_like_count&access_token=xxxx", "newlikes":"new_like_count"}';
     var jcontent= JSON.parse(link);
    var ulikes = document.getElementById("facelikes");
    ulikes.innerHTML = jcontent.newlikes + ' ';
```

```html
<div id="facelikes">blank</div>
```

This is what the json looks like

[image]

all help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are getting that **JSON** back then simply try to access the value like this.

> ulikes.innerHTML = jcontent.new_like_count+ ' ';

Here's a solution:

```
var link='{"url":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?fields=fan_count%2Cnew_like_count&access_token=xxxx", "newlikes":"new_like_count"}';
var jcontent= JSON.parse(link);
var ulikes = document.getElementById("facelikes");
ulikes.innerHTML = jcontent.new_like_count+ ' ';
```

Comment: How is it returning undefined if you are getting your JSON back? What is the exact value of var like ?

Comment: The value that i get on the log for the var ulikes is "undefined"

Comment: I guess I didn't make myself clear. What is the value of your variable "link"? are you sure you are getting that JSON back? go ahead and do console.log(link) to check what you are getting back and see it in the console.

Comment: you were right, i am not getting the json, the variable link is being treated as a string

Comment: @MikeStardust That's what I thought. I don t have your token value, but I know you can fix the value of link. I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want to get the data directly from the URL, use script callback

```
get_likes = function (u) {

    document.head.appendChild (

        Object.assign (

            document.createElement("script"), {

                src: u + "&callback=proc_likes"
            }
        )
    );
};

proc_likes = function (v) {

    /* Process Facebook API Output */
};
```

That is really as much as I can give you, try looking up the [Facebook Developer's Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is working code. You need to change `jcontent_newlikes` to `jcontent.new_like_count`.

```js
var link='{"fan_count": "706","new_like_count": "20","id":"185379184833085"}';
     var jcontent= JSON.parse(link);
    var ulikes = document.getElementById("facelikes");
    ulikes.innerHTML = jcontent.new_like_count + ' ';
```

```html
<div id="facelikes">blank</div>
```

Comment: the thing is i want the values to change thats why i want to get it from the facebook url

Comment: @MikeStardust Then change the value of `var link` to the JSON Facebook returned to you.